# Issue while looping through child records

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning, controller, after-trigger

I have a requirement to check for Role_Name__c on Account_Role__c object which is a child of Policy__c object. Now, if any child records have Original or Duplicate as value in Role_Name__c, a new Alert__c record should be created.

Below is my apex class:

```
public with sharing class Alertforpolicy {
    public static void UpdateFields() {
        List<Alert__c> CustAlertList = new List<Alert__c>();
        List<Policy__c> pollist = [SELECT id, Close_Date__c FROM Policy__c WHERE Close_Date__c = LAST_N_DAYS:30];
        for(Policy__c pol: pollist){
            for (Account_Role__c child : pol.Account_Roles__r)
            {
                if(child.Role_Name__c.contains('Duplicate') || child.Role_Name__c.contains('Original')){
                    Alert__c custalert = new Alert__c(
                        Contact__c = child.Contact__c,
                        Status__c = 'Active'
                    CustAlertList.add(custalert);
                }
            }
        }
        insert CustAlertList;    
    }
}
```

Now, this isn't working as expected. If there are 3 child account role records with given role names to a parent Policy__c record, 3 alert records should be created. That isn't happening here. No alert record is created.

Can anyone please suggest changes to the above code so that I can get this done.

Thanks!

Comment: where did you add Account_Roles__r in query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't query something, you don't get it from the database. You need to change your query:

```
    list<policy__c> pollist = [
        SELECT Close_Date__c,
        (SELECT Role_Name__c, Contact__c FROM Account_Roles__r)
        FROM policy__c 
        WHERE Close_Date__c = LAST_N_DAYS:30
    ];
```

Comment: No @sfdcfox, even with this updated query, alert__c records are not getting created.

Comment: @SFDCUser It may not be the entirety of the issue, but sfdcfox is very correct here. You can verify that his suggestion does indeed have an effect by putting a `system.debug()` in the block of your nested for loop, running your original code (you won't see any debug statements for that line in the debug log), and then running the code again after making the suggested modification (you will see debug statements, provided your data is set up correctly and your query filters are appropriate).